# Dplyr dataframe manipulation

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe.

```
# Input dataframe
Input <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(c(12001, 12002, 12003, 12001, 12002, 14000), origin = "1970-01-01"),
                    Model = as.factor(c("A","A","A","B","B","B")),
                    Cu = c(2,4,3,54,39,41),
                    Pb = c(9,10,7,22,25,19))
```

I must to convert the structure to the output example below using a ***single set*** of dpylr functions (pipes allowed %>%).

```
# Output dataframe
Output <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(c(12001, 12002), origin = "1970-01-01"),
                     Cu_A = c(2,4),
                     Cu_B = c(54,39),
                     Pb_A = c(9,10),
                     Pb_B = c(22,25))
```

Note: The factor column has now become part of the numeric column names. Also, dates that are not common between model A and model B are not present in the output (semi-join). The solution must be a single set of dplyr functions, because it will be used to create reactive Shiny dataframes.

Comment: I made an error, I will correct it, bare with me for a few minutes. Thanks.

Comment: Error in output dataframe has now be corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could keep only the dates which is part of every `Model` and get the data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
Input %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(Model) == n_distinct(.$Model)) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = Model, values_from = c(Cu, Pb))

#  Date        Cu_A  Cu_B  Pb_A  Pb_B
#  <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 2002-11-10     2    54     9    22
#2 2002-11-11     4    39    10    25
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    library(tidyr)
    library(dplyr)
    
Input %>% pivot_wider(names_from = Model, values_from = c(Cu, Pb), 
names_sep = "_") %>% filter_at(vars(-Date), all_vars(!is.na(.)))
```

Comment: Thanks, thats true. Even though it is already in wide form, we can make it even wider with pivot_wider. Good thinking.